# Missing plotting symbol for geom_point when using shape

Tags: r, ggplot2

I must be obviously missing something simple, or this is a small bug. The geom_point () is always missing a plotting symbol when the shape=factor is used. This does not happen when color=factor is used. Appreciate your help. Here is a test code.

```
test <- data.frame(let=sample(LETTERS,7), id=c(1:7), y=c(id*7))

ggplot(data=test, aes(x=id, y=y))+
geom_point(aes(shape=let), size=6)
```

"Notice here the missing point (only 6 out 7) as one of the symbol is missing, which usually is alphabetically the last factor"

```
ggplot(data=test, aes(x=id, y=y))+
geom_point(aes(color=let), size=6)
```

"Here we see 7 points with different colors"

Thanks, 
VJ

Comment: That's because `scales::shape_pal` defines a maximum of 6 values; try adding `scale_shape_manual(values=1:7)`

Comment: Thanks, that works! However, is this a known activity, or does the shape argument default to using a blank reference symbol/factor?

Comment: `scales::shape_pal()(7)` returns `16 17 15  3  7  8 NA`, and `grid.points(0.5, 0.5, pch=NA, def="npc")` doesn't draw anything.

Comment: I would think there should be a warning though, maybe you can check for a [bug report](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues)?

Comment: Actually, it does return the following warning:
Warning message:
Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
Never got around figuring it was due to the maximum shape parameters

Comment: I think there should be a more specific warning in `shape_pal` if you ask for more shapes than it can provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `scales::shape_pal` defines a maximum of 6 values; try adding `scale_shape_manual(values=1:7)`